# Unit Testing Servlet Filter with Mockito using HttpSession

Tags: java, unit-testing, jsp, servlets, mockito

I search for a long time how to do unit test with mockito and the class HttpSession. I haven't find anything so I'm asking here.

I have a web app in JavaEE. I implemented three filters that use a custom User class to log on the website. One filter by type of users. I have to test them with JUnit and Mockito. The only issue here, is that I don't succeeded to reproduce the behavior of the httpSession and httpServletRequest. 
When the test is passing through the filter code, when it comes to `session.getAttribute("User")`, it return a null pointer exception. 
Can you have a sight on this code please ? Basically, I need to emulate a session to get the "user" attribute and verify if the redirection is correct.

Filter code:

```
/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public RestrictionFilterCaseAdmin ( )
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


/**
 * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
 */
public void doFilter( ServletRequest req , ServletResponse res ,
                FilterChain chain )
                throws IOException , ServletException
{

    HttpServletRequest request = ( HttpServletRequest ) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = ( HttpServletResponse ) res;

    HttpSession session = request.getSession( );

    /* Creating temp user */
    if ( session.getAttribute( "User" ) != null ) {
        User userTmp = new User( );
        userTmp = ( User ) session.getAttribute( "User" );

        /**
         * If the user object don't exist, the user is not
         * connected.
         */
        if ( userTmp.getLogin( ) == null ) {
            /* Public page redirection */
            response.sendRedirect( request.getContextPath( )
                            + "/connexion" );
        } else if ( userTmp.getStatus( ).equals( "admin" ) ) {
            /* Restricted page redirection */
            chain.doFilter( request , response );
        } else {
            // User not allowed to dislay the page, go back
            // to home.
            response.sendRedirect( request.getContextPath( )
                            + "/redirect" );
        }
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect( request.getContextPath( )
                        + "/connexion" );
    }
}


@ Override
public void destroy( )
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@ Override
public void init( FilterConfig arg0 ) throws ServletException
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Test code:

```
@ Mock
HttpServletRequest  httpServletRequest;

@ Mock
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;

@ Mock
FilterChain     filterChain;

@ Mock
User            userTest;

@ Mock
HttpSession     sessionTest;


@ Before
public void setUp( )
{
    httpServletRequest = mock( HttpServletRequest.class );
    httpServletResponse = mock( HttpServletResponse.class );
    filterChain = mock( FilterChain.class );
    userTest = mock( User.class );
    sessionTest = mock( HttpSession.class );
}


@ Test
public void testDoFilter( ) throws IOException , ServletException
{
    userTest.setLogin( "test" );
    userTest.setPwd( "test" );
    userTest.setStatus( "admin" );
    sessionTest.setAttribute( "User" , userTest );
    when( sessionTest.getAttribute( "User" ) )
                    .thenReturn( userTest );
    when( httpServletRequest.getSession( true ) )
                    .thenReturn( sessionTest );
    when( httpServletRequest.getRequestURI( ) )
                    .thenReturn( "/Home.jsp" );
    RestrictionFilterCaseAdmin adminFilter = new RestrictionFilterCaseAdmin( );
    adminFilter.doFilter( httpServletRequest , httpServletResponse ,
                    filterChain );s
    verify( httpServletResponse ).sendRedirect(
                    "/restricted/admin/restrictedAdminTest.jsp" );
}
```

Thank you very much ! 
J.K

Answer (score 0):

The filter does this to get the session:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

But the test does this to set up the mock request to provide the mock session:

```
when( httpServletRequest.getSession(true)).thenReturn(sessionTest);
```

`request.getSession()` and `request.getSession(true)` are not the same method signature which results in a null session object and throws the exception.  Try changing the setup to:

```
when(httpServletRequest.getSession()).thenReturn(sessionTest);
```

Side note - the @Mock annotation creates the instance (assuming the test class is @RunWith(Mockito...)) so the code in `setUp` isn't needed.